# Azure Elastic Pool with Azure SQL Databases and MySQL databases

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-mysql-database, azure-elasticpool

Fast question:

Is it possible to have an Elastic Pool in Azure with Azure SQL Databases and MySQL databases?

Or in alternative an Elastic Pool made of Managed Instance and MySQL databases?

Comment: No, sorry.  It doesn't work that way.  An elastic pool is, under the covers, an instance of SQL Server hosting N databases where they share resources.

Comment: Cool. Can I do an Elastic Pool with only MySQLs databases?

Comment: I found an answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279553/azure-elastic-pool-is-it-supported-for-mysql

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani could you please post it as answer so the question shall be updated as answered

Comment: hi @IpsitaDash-MT. I'm actually writing an article about this topic to give more insights. I would like to add a quite more complete answer as it's something not so easy to understand. The post will be available in a few weeks. Thank you for caring about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @[Francesco Mantovani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4652358/francesco-mantovani). For now Lets post the answer that we have for now. Once you have your article ready, you can still post it as additional answer here.

**===
Cut from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279553/azure-elastic-pool-is-it-supported-for-mysql**

Azure DB for MySQL is similar as Azure SQL DB Elastic pool or Azure SQL DB managed instance.

> With Azure DB for MySQL server, we can create one or multiple DBs. We
> can >
>
> 1. Create a single DB per server to use all the resources or
> 2. Create multiple databases to share the resources.  The pricing is structured per-server, based on the configuration of pricing tier,
>    vCores, and storage (GB).

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-servers

Similarly in Azure SQL DB Elastic Pool

> Azure SQL DB elastic pools are cost-effective solution for managing
> and scaling multiple databases that have varying and unpredictable
> usage demands. The DBs in an elastic pool are on a single server and
> share a set number of resources at a set price. Elastic pools in Azure
> SQL DB enable SaaS developers to optimize the price performance for a
> group of databases within a prescribed budget while delivering
> performance elasticity for each database.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-overview

Only Azure SQL DB  has the feature to have multiple databases with separate physical resources in the same logical server.
In Azure DBs for MySQL, If you wish to have two DBs with their own dedicated resources, you need to have two separate Azure DBs for MySQL Servers.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with MadhurajVadde-MT:

> In Azure DBs for MySQL, If you wish to have two DBs with their own
> dedicated resources, you need to have two separate Azure DBs for MySQL
> Servers.

It might sound ridiculous but all Azure OSS servers are made to store several databases by default:

https://www.jeeja.biz/2021/08/26/lets-get-confused-azure-database-for-mysql-mariadb-postgresql-part-2/

You kinda have Elastic Pool by default.